# Looking for a Windows Application that can record television programs

Tags: windows-7, video-editing

I'm looking for a Windows application that can record television programs.

After recording is finished, I'd also like to edit these videos as well.

Comment: What hardware do you have (ie. Tv card?)

Comment: @rrirower: I probably need a recommendation for that too.

Comment: And, what type of editing?

Comment: @rrirower: I'd like to concate multiple TV clips, insert some personal video, and add titles and blurbs.

Comment: Does it have to be the same program? (i.e., recording *and* editing)

Comment: @Unor: No it doesn't.

Comment: @JimG. Please support this SE proposal: [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=pkyzvJvq0mtg1JcHSmnJDQ2)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of choices for TV tuners.  You're going to need to decide on a few things.  Do you want the USB stick style, an actual card that sits in your pc, or, the "set top box" style?  Most vendors provide these options.  There are advantages to each style.  For example, USB sticks provide portability.  In the past, I typically purchased the internal card because I built my own PVR (Personal Video Recorder).  Whatever style you pick, make sure it has **hardware encoding**.  You'll get much better performance.  The good news is, most also provide HD quality.  Another thing to consider is whether you want to watch one program while recording another (ie. dual tuner).  Some devices provide that also. I've built a few PVRs and have used the cards from [Hauppauge](http://www.hauppauge.com/).  Whatever you decide, do some research and plan ahead.

For software, each vendor typically bundles a third party package to handle the recording.  In my experiences, the software tends to be kluggy or hard to use.  However, there are choices.  You don't need to use the software that comes with the device.  I've used [SageTV](http://www.hauppauge.com/) to control my cards.  It's a much better PVR software product and easy to use.  If you decide on SageTV, be aware that they were bought by Goolge and have ceased development or support.  However, the software is still available [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/SageTV,0301-38230.html) and is supported via user forums.

As for the editing, that's not something that's typically bundled with the device.  For that, you'll need another 3rd party solution. I would recommend a package like [Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/).  I don't use it to edit tv recordings, but, I have used it to edit and create other videos.  The thing to make sure is that the editing software can edit the type of file that is produce d by the PVR.

Good luck...